# Swift I need to get weather data for all aver the day to table view

Tags: json, swift

[image]I have a question how to get in my table view weather for every day. On this moment by code that I have I get weather for every 3 hours as on the picture to my table view but I need weather for all over the day with minimum and maximum temperature values as 
March 27 Clouds 7  0 
March 28 Clouds 6  1,5
March 29 Clear  9  2
also for all over the day. I will be veery pleased for any responses. Thank you.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var cityNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var temperatureLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var weatherNowDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var weatherNowLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dailyWeatherTableView: UITableView!

var responseModel: WeatherForecast?
var degreeSymbol = "º"


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    currentWeatherRequest()
    dailyWeatherTableView.delegate = self
    dailyWeatherTableView.dataSource = self
    updateView()
    dailyWeatherTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    //self.dailyWeatherTableView.automatic
}
func currentWeatherRequest() {
let session = URLSession.shared
    let weatherURL = URL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Atlanta,us?&units=metric&APPID=apikey")!
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: weatherURL) { (data: Data?,response: URLResponse?,error: Error?) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error:\n\(error)")

        } else {
            if let jsonData = data {

                do {
                    let dataString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
          print("Daily weather data:\n\(dataString!)")
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()

                    self.responseModel = try decoder.decode(WeatherForecast.self, from: jsonData)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.cityNameLabel.text = self.responseModel?.city.name
                       self.weatherNowLabel.text = (self.responseModel?.list[0].weather[0].main).map { $0.rawValue }
                        self.weatherNowDescriptionLabel.text = self.responseModel?.list[0].weather[0].weatherDescription
                            self.dailyWeatherTableView.reloadData()
                        self.updateView()

                    }

                } catch let error {
                  print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")

        }
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()

}

 public func updateView(){

let temp = responseModel?.list[0].main
if let temperature = temp?.temp {
    self.temperatureLabel.text = "\(String(describing: temperature))\(self.degreeSymbol)"

} else {
    self.temperatureLabel.text = "No data"

}

}

  public    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return responseModel?.list[0...7].count ?? 7
}



 public     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FullDayWeatherCell", for: indexPath) as? DailyWeatherViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

let listArray = responseModel?.list[indexPath.row]
let maxTemp = listArray?.main
if let maxTemperature = maxTemp?.tempMax {
    cell.maxTempLabel.text = String(describing: maxTemperature)
} else {
    cell.maxTempLabel.text = "No data"
}
let minTemp = listArray?.main
if let minTemperature = minTemp?.tempMin {
    cell.minTempLabel.text = String(describing: minTemperature)
} else {
    cell.minTempLabel.text = "No data"
}
let weather = listArray?.weather[0]
let dayWeather = weather?.main
cell.weatherLabel.text = dayWeather.map { $0.rawValue }

let dateList = responseModel?.list[indexPath.row]
if let weekDate = dateList?.dt {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: (weekDate))
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMMd") // set template after setting locale
    print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
    cell.dayLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
} else {
    cell.dayLabel.text = "No data"
}

return cell


        }
private  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

}
```

I have this structure to parse JSON. I deleted from this code some structures that I don't use

```
import UIKit
// MARK: - WeatherForecast
struct WeatherForecast: Codable {
    let cod: String
    let message, cnt: Int
    let list: [List]
    let city: City
}

// MARK: - City
struct City: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let coord: Coord
    let country: String
    let population, timezone, sunrise, sunset: Int
}
// MARK: - List
struct List: Codable {
    let dt: Double
    let main: MainClass
    let weather: [Weather]
    let clouds: Clouds
    let wind: Wind
    let sys: Sys
    let dtTxt: String
    let rain, snow: Rain?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case dt, main, weather, clouds, wind, sys
        case dtTxt = "dt_txt"
        case rain, snow
    }    
}

// MARK: - MainClass
struct MainClass: Codable {
    let temp: Double
    let feelsLike, tempMin, tempMax: Double
    let pressure, seaLevel, grndLevel, humidity: Int
    let tempKf: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case temp = "temp"
        case feelsLike = "feels_like"
        case tempMin = "temp_min"
        case tempMax = "temp_max"
        case pressure
        case seaLevel = "sea_level"
        case grndLevel = "grnd_level"
        case humidity
        case tempKf = "temp_kf"
    }
}

// MARK: - Weather
struct Weather: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let main: MainEnum
    let weatherDescription, icon: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case main
        case weatherDescription = "description"
        case icon
    }   
}

enum MainEnum: String, Codable {
    case clear = "Clear"
    case clouds = "Clouds"
    case rain = "Rain"
    case snow = "Snow"
}
```

Comment: What does *for all over the day* mean? And why is `responseModel` optional? OpenWeatherMap sends very predictable data. If there is no error the weather data is reliable and has a value.

Comment: It’s not clear what your issue is, do you a problem with json decoding or with the table view or...? Please clarify your question

Comment: @vadian updated question with example

Comment: Group the forecast items by date and calculate the min and max values.

Comment: @vadian I add group by this way: let groupedDay = Dictionary(grouping: responseModel!.list, by: {$0.dtTxt}) but it grouped it by time not month and day

Comment: @vadian can you help to create group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I need weather for all over the day

Then you're using the wrong API. The OpenWeatherMap API that tells you the weather for entire days with max and min is:

https://openweathermap.org/forecast16

You are using the three-hour API; it does not tell you daily max and min values.